# JSON in Java (With JSON.simple)

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to make a JSON file using JSON.simple to fit requirements of a payload to a server.

The requirements are:

```
{
    "agent": {
        "name": "String",
        "version": 1
    },
    "username": "String",
    "password": "String",
    "clientToken": "String"
}
```

And also:

```
{
  "accessToken": "valid accessToken",
  "clientToken": "client identifier"   
  "selectedProfile": {                  
    "id": "profile identifier",         
    "name": "String"
  }
}
```

I've looked at a few posts to try and figure out how to achieve this but I just can't. All help appreciated :)

Comment: Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes.  Then understand that a JSON "object" is essentially equivalent to a Java Map, and a JSON "array" is pretty much like a Java List.

Comment: The second snippet is not valid JSON as you can check at http://jsonlint.com/.

Answer (score 0):

First create an object matching the json string. Then you could use some json parsers like [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) to read the values. For eg the first json contains an inner object agent. So we could first create a Java VO for that with field names matching the json string. The create a second object to hold everything. So it could be read as

```
import java.io.IOException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

class Agent {
    private String name;
    private int version;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getVersion() {
        return version;
    }
    public void setVersion(int version) {
        this.version = version;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Agent [name=" + name + ", version=" + version + "]";
    }
}

class User {

    private Agent agent;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String clientToken;

    public Agent getAgent() {
        return agent;
    }
    public void setAgent(Agent agent) {
        this.agent = agent;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getClientToken() {
        return clientToken;
    }
    public void setClientToken(String clientToken) {
        this.clientToken = clientToken;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [agent=" + agent + ", username=" + username
                + ", password=" + password + ", clientToken=" + clientToken
                + "]";
    }

}

public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = "{\"agent\":{\"name\":\"String\",\"version\":1},\"username\":\"String\",\"password\":\"String\",\"clientToken\":\"String\"}";

        //Gson way
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        User user = gson.fromJson(json, User.class);
        System.out.println(user);

        //Jackson way
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            user = mapper.readValue(json, User.class);
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(user);
    }

}
```

Comment: Just a part of it. For a starter. He still has one object more to map.. He could learn form this example. ;)

Comment: Cool, I can give this a try!